# Hilbert class field of Quadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Is there any method to find the Hilbert Class field of quadratic fields? Is there any bound for their dimensions? For example, if $4|d-1$ then $Q(\sqrt{d},i)$ is contained in the Hilbert class field of $Q(\sqrt{-d})$, therefore $Q(\sqrt{-d})$ isn't an UFD.

Comment: A book dedicated to this question is Cohen's Advanced Topics in Computational Number Theory.

Comment: It is not true that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d},i)$ is the Hilbert Class Field of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-d})$ in general when $4 | (d-1)$, just that it is contained in the Hilbert Class Field.

Comment: Observe that the ring of Integers of $Q(\sqrt{-d})$ when $d\equiv 1$ mod $4$ is not a UFD because the only ideal lying above $2$, which is ramified, cannot be principal (the integer $2$ is not a norm). The theory of complex multiplication (in case you did not know) relates the Hilbert class field of an imaginary quadratic filed K to the j-invariant of any elliptic curve with CM by the integers of K (one can learn this in "Primes of the form x^2+ny^2" by D.cox)

Comment: For your second question, the answer is no by genus theory:  The more primes that divide d, the bigger the class group.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of imaginary quadratic fields $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d_K})$, the Hilbert class field can be given as $K\left(j(\frac{d_k+\sqrt{d_k}}{2})\right)$, where $j$ is the [$j$-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant). This is just a theoretical answer; and note that computing $j(\frac{d_k+\sqrt{d_k}}{2})$ in practice, is not easy.